# Microsoft ace oledb 12.0 is not registered

Tags: visual-studio-2010

my application was running on windows 7 64 bit with office 2013
but because of some reasons, I had today to immigrate to windows 10 64 bit and office 2016 64 bit
the problem is , when I start the app it gives me the error:
Microsoft ace oledb 12.0 is not registered.
And even when I try to associate database file to vs studio 2010 ultimate,it gives me the same message
my app is the following:

````
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1
    Private mRow As Integer = 0
    Private newpage As Boolean = True
    Dim Table As New DataTable("Table")
    Dim pro As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim command As String
    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim dt As New DataTable
   
  




    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mokhtar\Documents\Database10.accdb"
        connstring = pro
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
        command = "insert into NewFolder ([NumD],[Objet],[Jur],[NomPA],[Info],[NomClient],[Tel],[Email],[Adr]) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NumD", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Objet", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Jur", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NomPA", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Info", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NomClient", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Tel", CType(TextBox7.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TextBox8.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Adr", CType(TextBox9.Text, String)))
        MsgBox("Record Save")
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myconnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()
            TextBox5.Clear()
            TextBox6.Clear()
            TextBox7.Clear()
            TextBox8.Clear()
            TextBox9.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub```

I don't know what to do
````

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem by setting the build configuration from x86 to any